# Solution of differential equation: domain vs integral of reciprocal of defining function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g:I\to \mathbb R$, $I\subset \mathbb R$, be the unique maximal solution of
$$y'=f(y)$$
$$y(a)=b$$
with $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ continuous.

Now I want to prove that $I=\mathbb R$ iff
$$\int_b^{+\infty} \frac1{f(t)}dt=+\infty \text{ and } \int_{-\infty}^b \frac1{f(t)}dt=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume $f(t)>0$ for the interval of times $t$ of interest.  Your ODE is $\frac{y'}{f(y)} = 1$.  This is separable and can be solved by integrating both sides.  If it helps, you can define $G(y) = \int_b^y \frac{1}{f(t)}dt$. Then look for when solutions $y(t)$ blow up in finite time.